# Jquery always repeat functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fadein

I have these 2 functions to create opacity effect

```
<script>
    function trans(id)
    {
       $(".pris_"+id).stop().fadeOut(1000);
       $(".pris_"+id).css({ opacity: 0.1});
       stop();
    }

    function trans_reverse(id)
    {
       $(".pris_"+id).stop().fadeIn(1000);
       $(".pris_"+id).css({ opacity: 0.8});
       stop();
    }
</script>


<div id="productos_image_soon" class="pris_1"    onmouseover="trans('1');"onmouseout="trans_reverse('1');">
   Product in a few time
</div>
```

Into the div i call each function , the problem is when i put mouseover the div all time and in recursive mode the second function execute and after the first function and continue executed , the effect is when mouseover the opacity low and when mouseout opacity grow

[Working ..... here jsfiddle.net/dSesq/](http://jsfiddle.net/dSesq/)

I don´t know why this happens, I've tried the stop() function but the problem continues

Comment: What's the standalone stop() function?

Comment: It does not make sense you are fading in the element, BUT you set the opacity of it? Why are you doing that second line. You want to use [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dSesq/ , you have there , regards

Comment: [`stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.stop) is not the same as [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes no sense why you are setting the opacity of the element after fading it in. Use fadeTo!

```
function trans(id, opacity) {
    $(".pris_"+id).stop().fadeTo( 1000, opacity);
}
```

And you should probably use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mousleave/). Also you are going to get weird results having the mouse over an element that is going to disappear.

Your code could be written as

```
$(".trigger").on("mouseover mouseout", function(evt){
    var opacity = evt.type=="mouseover" ? 1 : .8;
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(1000, opacity);    
})
```